# Bug with SQL Server Check Constraint?

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I have 3 tables, whose ID has different range. for example, table a has the ID <1000000, table b has the ID(from 10000001 to 2000000),table c has the ID>2000000. And I created the check constraint on the 3 tables according to the range of each table. Later, I created one view referencing the three tables using union all. When I query the view using the ID condition(=xxx), it will query only the table that stores the data and ignore querying the other 2 tables. It runs as what I expected.

But if the column type is char(xx), and I set the check constraint like (like 'a%' for table a , like 'b%' for table b, like 'c%' for table c). Then query the view using the name ='bcd'. After watching the execution plan, it will actually query the 3 tables. the check constraint doesnot help to ignore querying 2 tables that donot have the data.

So, my question is what is wrong when the check constraint referenced character column?

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#partitioned-views) explains:

> Constraint C1 defined on table T1 must be of the following form:
>
> ```
> C1 ::= < simple_interval > [ OR < simple_interval > OR ...]  
> < simple_interval > :: =   
> < col > { < | > | \<= | >= | = < value >}   
> | < col > BETWEEN < value1 > AND < value2 >  
> | < col > IN ( value_list )  
> | < col > { > | >= } < value1 > AND  
> < col > { < | <= } < value2 >
> ```

`LIKE` is not one of the allowed operations.

So, change the constraints to:

- tablea:  `col >= 'a' and col < 'b'`
- tableb:  `col >= 'b' and col < 'c'`
- tablec:  `col >= 'c' and col < 'd'`

Comment: got. tks very much

Comment: And when defining the check constraint, it allows the like operator. but actually it could not help improve the performance. so bad......

Comment: @WisonHe . . . What is allowed for a partitioned view is much more restricted than what is allowed for a check constraint.  The simple comparisons should be a bit faster than `like`, but `like` is reasonable.

Comment: hi Gordon. tks for your answer. actually the real condition is much more complicated than what I described above. For example,@ItemNumber LIKE '9XX%', @ItemNumber LIKE '%[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]-[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]-[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]%',etc. It could not convert to > operator easily,

Comment: @WisonHe . . . Then unfortunately, you cannot use partitioned views.

Comment: @WisonHem, I would expect partition elimination with `@ItemNumber LIKE '9XX%` but not the predicate with the leading wildcard.

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . If I hadn't read the documentation, I would agree with you.  If you are right, Microsoft should change the documentation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I did see static partition elimination with your check constraint examples and a query with `LIKE 'a%'.` But `LIKE 'b%'` touched both a and b tables and `LIKE 'c%'` touched b and c tables.

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . I think I misunderstood your comment.  You were referring to the query and whether the partitions were eliminated; I was thinking of the conditions in the `check` constraint.